Android Virtual Device won't run due to HAXM error (Android Studio)
What happens to Android Studio? I tried to run Android Emulator, I already installed HAXM, but it gets errors below.
I tried enabling the Intel Virtualization in BIOS setting already. But I can't find what to do next to let the Android Studio run, because it seems the program won't detect HAXM, and won't let me test the emulator.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/HXP2m.jpg)

Does this answer your question? I can't install intel HAXM

Check that virtualization is enable in BIOS settings

Todo this restart the device and enter bios settings
Search for virtualization can be under system settings the turn it on.

Hints: Virtualization can be indicated by something like (Vtx)

if on windows try installing Hypervisor driver through searching in the search "Features" the choose install and select it from a list displayed to you


The Intel Virtualization Technology in the Bios setting is already enabled but It seems the virtual device failed to run with the haxm (it said failed to install haxm)
I even try the "sc query intelhaxm" method in cmd and it reported 4 running. I don't know what's wrong
